# setting text file in gitattributes doesn't work

Tags: git

[image]

In revision 0810a7, I set to always treat .cs file as text.

Then later in revision b83cd8, I changed a cs file. But I see the diff in command line, Git thinks it's a binary file.

[image]

Did I write the attributes file wrongly? How to make Git treat the file as text?

Comment: What is the encoding of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.gitattributes` setting named `text` tells Git to treat the file as text for end-of-line manipulation purposes, but does not control whether Git treats the file as text for `git diff` purposes.

The `git diff` control knob is the `diff` setting:

```
*.cs text diff
```

will force `git diff` to diff `*.cs` files as text too.